# Coverting PHP login script to use prepared statements

Tags: php

I'm trying to learn to convert a PHP login page to use prepared SQL statements with parameters versus just using standard script to protect from SQL injection.  Its for a security class and not a programming class and my PHP is weak and be will evident.  I can't figure out why I'm not getting any results from the execution. Its using PDO, and I've switch from bindParam to bindValue as suggested on other topics, but I still get a black page from the login.

My db connection is working, and I think my SQL statement and parameters are correct. I really believe the problem is in retrieving the results.  Can anyone help why I can get a row count?  I've also tried with $stmt->count_rows

```
<html>
<body>

<?php

$db_hostname  = 'localhost';
$db_username  = 'testuser';
$db_password  = '1234';
$db_dbname    = 'testdb';
$db_tablename = 'users';
$db_conn_str  = "mysql:host=" . $db_hostname . ";dbname=" . $db_dbname;

try {

    $db   = new PDO($db_conn_str, $db_username, $db_password);
    $stmt = $db->prepare("Select * from users where login = ? and passwd = ?");
    $stmt->bindValue(1, $_POST['username']);
    $stmt->bindValue(2, $_POST['password']);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->store_result();
    $result = $stmt->fetchAll();

    $num = $result->rowCount();

    $stmt->close();
}
catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo "Error in PDO: " . $e->getMessage();
}


if ($num == 0) {
    echo "login failed! <br />";
} else {
    $name = $result->fetchColumn(0);
    echo "Welcome, $name!<br />";
}
?>
```

Comment: $num=$db->rowCount();

Comment: You should not store password as plain password in database. That's a huge no no.

Comment: `store_result` is mysqli, not PDO. `rowCount` is a part of the PDO statement, not result. If you'd check your error logs, you should see some errors relating to this.

Comment: You're also missing a semi-colon at the end of your hostname declaration.

Comment: Being a simple test of rewriting the PHP for prepared statements, I think they didn't want to make it more complex on hashing password values in the table.  The DB, initial html, and login.php were given.

Comment: So this is your homework then?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I mix MySQL APIs in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17498216/can-i-mix-mysql-apis-in-php)

Comment: It is important to use password_hash and password_verify functions. It looks like you are using plain text passwords here. Also, on any site that accepts passwords make sure that you are using https and not http.

Comment: Learn how to check error logs. They will save you a lot of time in the long run. Also, learn how to enable MySQL error checking in PHP.

Comment: Thanks for all the tips everyone.  Overall I think mixing up PDO and mysqli was the biggest issue minus the syntax erros

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few issues.

- Syntax error after `$db_hostname='localhost'`
- PDO does not have a `store_result()` method, that's a mysqli method.
- Turn off emulated prepared querys. `ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES`
- You need to also tell PDO to throw Exceptions else it wont `ERRMODE_EXCEPTION`
- Also `$result->fetchColumn(0);` will fetch the first column so presuming that `id` your welcome message would say `Welcome, 1`.
- Just count fetchAll() instead of rowCount().
- Don't forget `htmlentities()` to protect against stored XSS

Below is changed code:

```
<?php
$db_hostname='localhost';
$db_username='testuser';
$db_password='1234';
$db_dbname='testdb';
$db_tablename='users';
$db_conn_str="mysql:host=" . $db_hostname . ";dbname=" . $db_dbname;

try {
  $db = new PDO($db_conn_str, $db_username, $db_password);
  $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
  $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);

  $stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE login = ? AND passwd = ?");

  $stmt->bindValue(1, $_POST['username']);
  $stmt->bindValue(2, $_POST['password']);
  $stmt->execute();

  $result = $stmt->fetchAll();

  if (count($result) == 0) {
    echo "login failed! <br />";
  } else {
    echo "Welcome, ".htmlentities($result[0]['name'])."!<br />";
  }

  $stmt->close();
} catch (PDOException $e) {
  echo "Error in PDO: " . $e->getMessage();
}
?>
```

You should also look into using [password_*](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.password.php) based functions instead of storing your passwords as plaintext.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks.  I had to look up the PDO options and just overlooked counting $results.